# MVC 4 Web API Areas 404 Error: "The controller for path '/Jobs/Send' was not found or does not implement IController."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue that is driving me nuts.

I have an MVC 4 WebAPI application that has several Areas defined.

My Jobs Area Send controller (SendController.cs) is defined like so:

```
namespace TargetAPI.Areas.Jobs.Controllers
{
    public class SendController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Index(SendRequest req)
        {
            try
            {
            //blah blah
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            //blah blah
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Jobs Area Registration (JobsAreaRegistration.cs) is defined like so:

```
namespace TargetAPI.Areas.Jobs
{
    public class JobsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Jobs";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Jobs_long",
                "Jobs/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "TargetAPI.Areas.Jobs.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My RouteConfig.cs says:

```
namespace TargetAPI
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                     action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional },
                 namespaces: new string[] { "TargetAPI.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the route debugger on it I get: 
[image: My Route Debug]
<sub>(source: [boomerang.com](http://imagestore2.boomerang.com/img/temp/routedebug.jpg))</sub>

But when I try to post to the URL "Jobs/Send"  I get:

The controller for path '/Jobs/Send' was not found or does not implement IController.

I've tried so many iterations and combinations my head is spinning.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Turns out the WebAPI does NOT handles Areas!  Imagine my surprise.   So I found a GREAT post http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/.  Now I am moving forward.

Comment: Wow, how unfortunate. a day of googling, and finally found this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to not supporting Areas (because MapHTTPRoute doesn't have namespace support), The API controller must use MapHttpRoute, not MapRoute as in this example (after removing area):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

    }
```

Note the absence of {action}, the Method's are not Actions, put are taken from the HTTP request: Get, Head, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was simple: I forgot to add files `_ViewStart.cshtml` and `_Layout.cshtml`, and can help you